# Repeat a directive in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which build a star icon. I want to repeat it 'n' times. And then I want to change the class in 'active' to 'n' stars. 
This is the directive which build a star and, on click, it add the class 'active'.

```
<div ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="ctrl">
   <div class="presentation">
      <button-star repeatStars="7" limitActiveStar="5" classToAdd="active"></button-star>
</div>
```

```
.directive('buttonStar', function() {
  return {
  scope: {
      repeatStars: "=",
      limitActiveStar: "=",
      classToAdd: "="
  },
  restrict: 'E',
  template: '<button class="btn btn-icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></button>',
  link: function(scope, elem) {
    elem.addClass('active'); 
  }
 };
})
```

So, in my example, I'd like to repeat the directive 7 times and add to the first 5 elements the class 'active'

Comment: what did you tried ?

Comment: The code above, but I don't know how to go on

Comment: what is the expected dom html after rendering this directive ?

Comment: The expected dom , in my example, is seven icons including five active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your controller :

```
$scope.number = 7;
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
```

then

```
<button-star ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index" repeat-stars="7" limit-active-star="5" class-to-add="{{$index < 5 ? 'active' : ''}}"></button-star>
```

should work

Comment: Console error: element is not defined http://plnkr.co/edit/uUiKWuJ8tSZUOKAW8pAs?p=preview

Comment: i have no error with your plnk, i edit my answer but it's working for me

Comment: i forgot the {{...}} for the class-to-add ^^

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use a ng-repeat directive in that case ?
admitting you have 7 items in `items`

`<button-star ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-class="{'active': $index < 5}">`

Answer (score 0):

I made a plunker with a working solution, here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/kX9yXUVwOC7ZD0qnyMt7?p=preview

I created a parent directive called `buttonStars` that has several child directive elements `buttonStar` inside it. The first `limitActiveStars` will have the class `active` added to them, while the rest won't have it.